# Overload operator* to get reference to instance of another class

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism, operator-overloading, abstract-class

I have classes

```
class Square
{
public:
    virtual void apply(Player*) = 0; //apply square effect to the player
};

class BoardIterator
{
public:
    BoardIterator();
    Square &operator*();//return current square where player is
    Square &operator+(int);//move forward certain number of squares
private:
    static const int pathLength = 8;//length of outer path
    static const int innerPathLength = 4;//length of inner path
    int curPosition;//number of current square
    Square *outerPath[pathLength];
    Square *innerPath[innerPathLength];
};

class UpdateStatusSquare : public Board::Square
{
public:
    void apply(Player*);
};

/*
Square where player can choose career path
*/
class CareerSquaere : public Board::Square
{ 
public:
    void apply(Player*);
};
```

*boardIterator has to return reference to Square object.
This is my implementation of this operator

```
Board::Square& Board::BoardIterator::operator*()
{
     return *(outerPath[curPosition]);
}
```

I try to test this in this way

```
Board::BoardIterator iter;
UpdateStatusSquare x = *iter;
```

But I have

> Error C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'Board::Square' to
>   'UpdateStatusSquare'  CareersGame

How should I implement this overloading in right way?

Comment: For starters, your `*` overload does not return a pointer, but a reference (which is correct, but you need to use the right terminology). Furthermore "But cant get pointer" is not a useful problem description. You need to [edit] your question and explain exactly what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### What's the problem ?

The error message of another compiler could shed some light on the issue:

> error: conversion from ‘Square’ to non-scalar type
> ‘UpdateStatusSquare’ requested

You have defined the `operator*()` of your `BoardIterator` to return a reference to a `Square`, not a `UpdateStatusSquare`.  And this works in fact very well, if used as designed:

```
BoardIterator iter;
Square& x = *iter;   // no compiler issue ! I could use x later on
```

Your original assignment causes a problem, because the compiler doesn't know how to convert a `Square` into an `UpdateStatusSquare`.  How could the compiler do this if the square you return would be a `CareerSquaere` ?

### How to solve it ?

You need to handle abstract polymorphic classes with care.  First, if you do value assignment as you tried, you might [slice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) the returned object.  So best use references, pointers (or better, smart pointers).

Now transforming a `Square` (without knowing what specific kind of square it is) into an `UpdateStatusSquare` is called [downcasting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Downcasting). You can do it, but with extra extra care, using a [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast):

```
UpdateStatusSquare *it = dynamic_cast<UpdateStatusSquare*>(&*iter);
if (it) {
    // conversion worked the iterator pointed to a compatible type
}
else {
    // it==nullptr because iterator pointed to an incompatible kind of square
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/w6mEjt)

Comment: outerPath array I will fill with objects of UpdateStatusSquare or CareerSquaere classes, and how to cast elements of this array to corresponding class further? If I will call apply function for some of this elements, how to make the function work as defined in the class of the corresponding element?

Comment: outerPath is an array of Square pointers.  So you don't need to care: each of these pointers could point to any kind of squares.  And the returned reference could also refer to any kind of squares.